# Google Drive API Node.js Search files in specific location

Tags: javascript, search, directory, drive

I'm trying to look for files in a specific folder on Drive using the API. The reason herefor is that my files can have copies with the same name in multiple folders. This is a sniplet of what I wrote to check if the files exist but the resulting query is Undifined. Anyone got an idea?

```
function checkFile(filename, auth, folderId){
var service = google.drive('v3');
console.log("folderId: " + folderId);
var objectExists = false;
var fetchPage = function(pageToken, pageFn, callback) {
  service.files.list({auth: auth,
    resource: { parents: [ folderId ] },
    q: "mimeType='application/pdf' and trashed=false",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    spaces: 'drive',
    pageToken: pageToken,
  }, function(err, res) {
    if(err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res)
        if(res.files != undefined){
            res.files.forEach(function(file) {
              if(file.name == filename)
              {
                console.log('Found file: ', file.name, file.id);
                objectExists = true;
              }

              });
              if (res.nextPageToken) {
                pageFn(res.nextPageToken, pageFn, callback);
              } else {
                callback();
              }
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }

    }
  });
};
fetchPage(null, fetchPage, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
        if(!objectExists)
            createFile(filename, auth, folderId)
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding more data in fields:

```
fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name),files/parents',
```

Followed by adding an extra check-value:

```
if(file.name == filename && file.parents[0] == folderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Akorna I found your question relating to my search would you mind If I ask for a beginner level code for searching on GOOGLE drive API in Nodejs
I have a skeleton code ready and have configured the drive for it through service account.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis') ;
const readLine = require('readline');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const { file } = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/file');
dotenv.config();

const KEYFILEPATH = path.join(__dirname, '/credentials.json');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'profile'];

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYFILEPATH,
    scopes: SCOPES
  });

const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
```